# How do I translate an Adobe XD color into a Native react code?

Tags: react-native, adobe-xd

I worked on the design of an application with Adobe Xd, and I’m looking for a way to convert it as much as possible in order to facilitate the coding work. In particular, I used the react Native Generator plug-in to translate my views.
By modifying the code a bit and trying to integrate it into my application, I realized that the background colors are not taken into account.
Is there a way to recover this one?
Ps: I’m a beginner in native reaction

Answer (score 0):

there is some plugin called Advanced Export Can give you Code of Colors

Also in SHARE Tab in Adobe XD 2020 you can export colors as CSS variable